# Как организовать поиск mysql

Tags: php, mysql, поиск, search

Есть 2 таблицы

1. directories

   - id
   - parent_id
   - title
2. files

   - id
   - directory_id
   - title

Как сделать поиск вида?

- категория (сколько файлов)
- категория2 (сколько файлов)
- ...

Что бы выводило не все категории, а только те, в которых найдены файлы. В категориях могут быть и подкатегории.

Поиск по полю `files.title`.

Comment: как категории связаны с файлами?

Comment: directories.id связан с files.directory_id

Comment: Господи что за каша? Связь directory_id с id   один ко многим или многие к одному? Пример вашего запроса напишите и конкретно что не получается.

Comment: sy2nyk видимо хочет рекурсию, не самая простая задача. может ее упростить немного удорожив запись (писать в запись файла путь до него при апдейте файла либо ветки директорий (смена parent например)  ? Так в файлухах обычно не делается, но тут может быть такой оверхед будет к месту.

Comment: @sy2nyk, вам еще актуален ваш вопрос?.. Если да - уточните подробности и текущую ситуацию пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем ясно, что хотите получить, попробуйте переформулировать вопрос.
Неясно, какая связь между данными, что именно хотите получить в результате, что уже сделали, и в чем конкретно затруднение.

Из того, что читается сейчас: мы ищем по files.title, каждый file принадлежит категории, верно? Получается, в результате поиска у нас например набор files.title с соответствующими им категориями, пустые не относящиеся к делу категории в выдаче не появятся. Вам нужно это или что-то другое? Если да - тогда что-то в этом роде например:

```
SELECT title,id,count(*) FROM (
  SELECT directories.title, directories.id
    FROM directories
    INNER JOIN files
      ON directories.id=files.directory_id
  WHERE files.title='cat' ) as T 
 GROUP BY id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a1e9/3 Это для тех директорий, в которых непосредственно лежит файл, без учета родителей.

Не совсем ясно про подкатегории - как считать хотите?

- Файл входит в поддиректорию и тогда должно выдавать *директория - 1
  файл поддиректория - 1 файл?*
- Файл лежит в двух поддиректориях - должно выдать *директория - 2
  файла, поддиректория1 - 1 файл, поддиректория2 - 1 файл?* Или как?

Обе ситуации слегка сбивают с толку, если выводить таким образом - получаются неявные дубликаты. Надо тогда как минимум показывать иерархию.
Типа:

```
В мире 4 кошки, из них:
 В Европе 3 кошки, из них
    У Мэри 1 кошка
    У Джона 1 кошка
   в Европе 1 кошка (это Бродячая Европейская)
 В России 1 кошка, из них
    У Васи 1 кошка
```

Наверное можно вытащить полные пути в сводную (pivot) таблицу с помощью [mysql flow control statements] (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/flow-control-statements.html) в запросе, или сделать [хранимую процедуру](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0) MySQL.

Взгляните также https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513418/how-to-do-the-recursive-select-query-in-mysql

Cписок перентов хранить можно как строку с разделителем - при вставлении файла обновлять в самой записи файла, типа 0/10/22/14.

Еще вариант - поиск родителей делать не в базе, а вынести в бизнес-логику.
Еще можно хранить древовидную структуру [так](http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/databases/mysql/handling-hierarchical-data-in-mysql-and-php.html).

> So, which model is better? It depends. If you need a more flexible
>   model that can be easily updated, use the adjacency list model. In
>   case you have a complex tree that does not need to be updated
>   frequently, choose the nested set model.

Вот еще [большая презентация](http://www.slideshare.net/quipo/trees-in-the-database-advanced-data-structures) на тему древовидных структур. Какие у вас приоритеты неясно.

Если добавите в вопрос конкретные данные, предполагаемый результат, и код, который получилось написать - на их примере будет легче разобраться, что вам нужно и написать запрос. Можно воспользоваться http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Простите а зачем "выбирать" d.title и "количество" из d.title и f.title и группировать это всё по d.title?

Comment: @barmaglott, ну как я понял желаемый результат - названия категорий (d.title) с количеством (count, group by) соответствующих (inner join) файлов. Вам кажется, что мой запрос делает нечто другое? Тогда уточните пожалуйста в чем именно ошибка, и как правильно. Или вы желаемый результат иначе видите?

Comment: @barmaglott, группировать по d.id, исправил

Comment: "Путь к файлу возможен единственный или он может входить в несколько "веток"?"

parent_id один на запись, значит путь один.

Comment: @konst54 Да ничего ваш запрос не делает НИЧЕГО. Группировать можно только по ВЫБРАННЫМ из БД столбцам. Вы же "выбираете" только "d.title". КАК прости меня господи вы будете по "id" группировать(из БД вы "id" не выбирали)? Что у вас "Count(*)" делает(кол-во выбранных строк и так любая СУБД в выводе показыват)? ЗАЧЕМ вам внешний запрос? Не хотите вы "files.title" выбирать НЕ ВЫБИРАЙТЕ.

Comment: @konst54О каких путях в "parent_id" вы говорите? Насколько я эту структуру БД понимаю(кстати почему автор ничего не поясняет?) в "parent_id" хранится НОМЕР(поле типа INT) родительской папки И ВСЁ. Хотите узнать путь реализуйте логику в бизнес слое или в самом запросе. Кстати какие нафиг КАТЕГОРИИ? Может всё-таки папки или на худой конец директории?

Comment: @barmaglott про пути - я имел в виду, может ли файл находиться в нескольких директориях сразу, но как обратил внимание eicto,  parent_id один на запись, значит путь один, этот вопрос снят. Спасибо, что обратили внимание на ошибки в запросе, немного позже перепишу.

Comment: @barmaglott, исправил запрос.